# Glympse REST API: How to identify the device if userId and password are lost

Tags: glympse

I'm storing the userId and password generated by the `account/create` endpoint in the browser's `localStorage`, in order to use them for all subsequent logins.

However, in case the localStorage gets cleared, I still want to be able to retrieve the account history, favorites, etc, so simply logging in with a new account doesn't seem to be the right way to go.

Is there any way to identify the user and retrieve their history/favorites even if the `userId/password` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If credentials are stored in localStorage, and the localStorage is cleared there is no way to restore the account though the Glympse REST API.

If the account is linked through another service then it is possible to manually restore the account. Currently the services linked to Glympse are Facebook, Twitter, and Google+.

You can also restore an account through text message or email.

There is no API request for retrieving account information by other means (for example, a database query for collections matching "_id" or "email_address"), because that would be out of the scope of the Glympse REST API's purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What I ended up doing is persisting the userId and password somewhere safer than the localStorage, and that works just fine.